# print method in java doesn't print content of jtable

Tags: java, swing, printing

The print button below displays the printer selection window but it prints nothing ...but the JTable contains data

```
print_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            boolean complete = table2.print();
            if (complete) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done printing");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "printing.....");
            }
        } catch (PrinterException pe) {
    }
}});
```

Comment: plz catch error in catch block.don't leave empty.use `pe.printStackTrace()`

Comment: what will be the content f the catch error

Comment: We need the code for table2 and especially the print method, otherwise we can't help

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim  may be you are geting some exception when printing .so add `pe.printStackTrace()` see it.

Comment: table2 displays data retrieved from database
i do not have a printing method....may be you can help me there

Comment: @Iamsomeone `print()` is a method of `jtable` class .

Comment: Let me get this straight. You post a question, saying the "print method" ... "does not print [the] content of [the] jtable". You use the word print throughout. Your code has the line `table.print()` in it. You tagged your question `printing`. And now you say "i do not have a printing method". Really??

Comment: @dcsohl  `print()` is a method of `jtable` class."i do not have a printing method" probably it's not written by him.it's inbuilt method.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html

Comment: And he is calling that `print()` metho, and nobody said it was **his** method, *per se*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a *size* to your `JTable` in order to get printed:

```
table2.setSize(table2.getPreferredSize());
```

It's correct that it has data, but it needs to have a size for the priniting to work.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

```
    print_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("report printing");

            MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("page{0,number,integer}");

            try {
                table1.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL,header,footer);
            } catch (PrinterException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

    }});
```